# winforms and want to learn how to develop project in winfoms using C#

Tags: .net, winforms, web-to-winforms

Can anyone provide me with info about learning about Winforms projects. I am starting new job where I have to work on winforms. Prior to this job, I have mostly worked on Web applications in ASP.NET and C#. So I am familiar with certain features of C#. What are the kind of projects that use winforms?

Answer (score 1):

Winform applications are non-hosted applications- they behave exactly as any other .exe on a Windows system.  You will find that most of the tools you use in ASP.NET translate to some close equivalent on the Winform side, although your approach to layout control is probably going to have to change dramatically.

Beyond UI, there aren't many real differences.  Statelessness is no longer required, so you can hold a few things in memory without getting yelled at if you're writing an application to work against a database or other external source, but by and large it will feel much the same as what you've been doing.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of things you could do. Picking up a good winforms book isn't a terribly bad idea (an amazon.com search for winforms brings up a plethora).

For online info, the [Getting Started](http://windowsclient.net/getstarted/) page of windowsclient.net is a good launchpad to get you started.

It's also common that companies will use specific toolsets (ie. DevExpress, Infragistics, etc.) so poking through their docs if you're using any of those is a must.

Otherwise, practice. Re-implement UI functionality that you've done in an ASP.NET project as a winforms app and maybe try to extend it. Or mimic the UI of a program you use already.

As to the last part of your question: Pretty much any windows program that has a UI can be implemented in winforms (unless it uses WPF specific functionality) so you've likely already used many winforms apps.

Answer (score 0):

That's a little vague... most Windows applications use Winforms, although there is a move towards WPF.  WPF uses XAML which is the same markup language that Silverlight uses.

Do you have specific questions about Winforms?  Those might be a little easier to answer.